# Calculate distances using Google Maps

Tags: asp.net, maps, distance, calculator

I am creating a  business directory website which has street addresses stored in the database. I would like to calculate the distance from a given zipcode to the street address using google maps in ASP.Net.
I don't even know where to begin. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

please see the links below

http://briancray.com/2009/04/01/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-addresses-with-javascript-and-google-maps-api/

http://briancray.com/2009/06/23/calculate-driving-distance-google-maps-api/

http://www.ehow.com/how_5142324_calculate-distance-google-maps.html